# How to fix data type conversion SQL error in ABAP when using VBRK and VBRP

Tags: sql, abap, sqldatatypes

I want to get the sum of quantities billed in a fixed period and a defined organisation but It either prints 0 or I get an SQL error as in the screenshot.[image: the error]

I used tables VBRK for Organisation and data and VBRP for quantity and currency.

```
   Tables: VBRK,
        lips,
        VBRP.


TYPES: Begin of itab5,

   VKORG TYPE VBRK-VKORG,
   FKDAT TYPE VBRK-FKDAT,
   ARKTX TYPE LIPS-ARKTX,
   FKIMG TYPE VBRP-FKIMG,
   VRKME TYPE VBRP-VRKME,

 End of itab5.

DATA: wa_ma5 TYPE itab5,
      it_ma5 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF itab5,
      quan TYPE VBRP-FKIMG,
      curr TYPE vbrp-vrkme.
SELECT-OPTIONS: DATE FOR VBRK-FKDAT.
SELECT-OPTIONS: Organ FOR VBRK-VKORG.
APPEND date.
APPEND Organ.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  SELECT VKORG FKDAT FKIMG VRKME FROM VBRK
    inner JOIN VBRP ON VBRP~netwr = VBRK~WAERK
     INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE it_ma5
     WHERE VBRK~FKDAT IN DATE AND VBRK~VKORG IN Organ.

END-OF-SELECTION.

  quan = 0.

  LOOP AT it_ma5 INTO wa_ma5.
*    if sy-subrc = 0.
    quan = quan + wa_ma5-fkimg.

*    endif.

  ENDLOOP.

  WRITE: 'the quantity', quan.
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not that complicated.
You are doing join between the two tables using **VBRP-NETWR** and **VBRK-WAERK** which doesn't make sense (and they are different data types).

**VBRK** is linked with **VBRP** by **VBELN** field (one is billing header and one billing items), so the correct JOIN is:

```
START-OF-SELECTION.
  SELECT vkorg fkdat fkimg vrkme
    FROM vbrk
   INNER JOIN vbrp
      ON vbrp~vbeln = vbrk~vbeln
    INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE it_ma5
   WHERE vbrk~fkdat IN date
     AND vbrk~vkorg IN organ.
```